# Working with list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list of 10-tuples in Haskell and I want to get nth tuple from that list of tuples. But as I saw, only **length** function worked with that list. **head**, **tail** or **!!** functions didn't work. Can you tell me what should I do? The tuples are composed of integers and strings. 
For example when I try this :

```
tail [(3,5,"String1","String2","String3","String4","String5","String6","String7","String8"),(3,5,"String1","String2","String3","String4","String5","String6","String7","String8"),(3,5,"String1","String2","String3","String4","String5","String6","String7","String8")]
```

I get this error message from hugs:

```
ERROR - Cannot find "show" function for:
*** Expression : tail [(3,5,"String1","String2","String3","String4","String5","String6","String7","String8"),(3,5,"String1","String2","String3","String4","String5","String6","String7","String8"),(3,5,"String1","String2","String3","String4","String5","String6","String7","String8")]
*** Of type    : [(Integer,Integer,[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char])]
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly for me and gives `[(3,5,"String1","String2","String3","String4","String5","String6","String7","String8"),(3,5,"String1","String2","String3","String4","String5","String6","String7","String8")]`. However, you're still better off with structures than these giant tuples.

Comment: What interpreter are you using? It looks like Hugs to me... GHCi has supported tuples up to 60 components (including Show instances, which is the problem here) since version 6.12.2 - released in 2010 - at the very least.

Comment: Thank you for warning me. I am using hugs. After reading what you said I saw that it works on ghci, but it doesn't work on hugs. What should I do to make it work on hugs too? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Write your own `Show` instance for tuples with more than 7 (IIRC) components. But the last release of hugs is from fall 2006, so hugs is pretty much dead. Sad, but that's life. Move to ghci, that comes with a compiler for additional goodness.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. Can you give me a hint so that I could write that? I have never written a Show instance before. Thanks

Comment: `instance (Show a, Show b,...) => Show (a,b,...) where show (x,y,...) = "(" ++ show x ++ "," ++ show y ++ ... ++ ")"`. Elementary, but tedious. Of course you can automate the instance generation.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I didn't know Hugs had Template Haskell ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to declare a `Show` instance for a 3-tuple. Hopefully this illustrates the idea and you can extend it to more elements:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)

instance (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Show (a, b, c) where
  show (a, b, c) = "(" ++ (intercalate "," ([show a, show b, show c])) ++ ")"
```

You can read the instance declaration just like logical implication: *if* I can show values of type a, b, and c, *then* I can show a tuple of type (a, b, c), and here's how.

GHC defines a Show instance for everything up to a 15-tuple, so you probably won't need to define this in your case.